# OpenLayers does not request tiles at low zoom level after updating the view with a new projection

Tags: python-requests, openlayers, projection, tiles, zoom-sdk

At zoom level close to 0, if I update the view with a new projection, OpenLayers doesn't request all the tiles, only some of them. I have to pan or zoom in and out to make it request all the tiles.

I can understand that this s useless if I only update the zoom level or the center, updating the projection should cause all tiles to be requested from the server.

Is this a bug or is any there a way (or workaround) through configuration or code to make OpenLayers request all tiles after changing the projection?

Note that I disabled the browser cache.

Comment: Are you doing something similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/projection-and-scale.html but with more projections?  If so which projections.  Also what is the native projection of the base layer?

Comment: No, I don't care about keeping the exact same resolution. I just want to change the projection at world extent level, and then see all the tiles requested. I've tried switching from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326 and back again. The native projection of my base layer is EPSG:4326, but the same happens with several external WMS servers.

Comment: I think it is making too many requests to the WMS server - I found a similar problem in one of the OpenLayers examples and reported it https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13866

Comment: I don't think as I don't see a lot of requests coming out from my OpenLayers client when look at them with DevTools. The requests are in fact much less than normal.

Comment: I have implemented a workaround by applying a refresh to base maps that have a global extent right after a projection change at low zoom levels. But to me the problem looks like a bug of OpenLayers. By the way I am using OpenLayers version 6.12.0.